# Cannot Install Ubuntu on Older Workstation

Tags: 12.04

This is my first time working with linux. I have an HP xw4400 workstation that I'm trying to install Ubuntu on. I have tried the 14.04 installation CD and a 12.04 minimal install disc neither of which seem to work. I want to focus on the 12.04 minimal cd install for this question. I run the cd and it comes up to the part where it is boot> I type in cli the disk drive spins and finally stops and the blank screen. What do I need to do to get this to work past this point.

Comment: I have the same workstation and config. I tried all of the versions of UBUNTU, and all of them fail to load. They even fail to run off the USB stick

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Ubutnu if you already have a OS(Windows) running try opening the CD from Windows, this might be a problem with the CD Burning or the DVD reader. If it taking time opening the CD in windows that means while booting CD is not getting enough time to boot. for this you need to try multiple times to booting from CD.

if it opened fine in windows then it might be problem with Burning the CD.